# How can I hit save this end point on my own server and make an API call to it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

Apologies if this question is a little too niche/ specific but I'm stumped and don't know where else to go for answers. I am using [this](https://docs.sleeper.app/#players) API to make a fantasy football newletter type app for a league I'm in, and trying to display player's names on the page. The problem however, is that they are stored in the API as just player ID numbers. The /players endpoint they provide is where the id's are matched up to the data I'm looking for (name, team, etc). In the documentation however, it says to only use that endpoint at most once per day, as the data set is over 5MB, and to save the information to my own server.

I am still a new developer, so I'm a bit confused as to how I can:

1. Save this information on my end
2. Matchup the ID numbers I am already retrieving and displaying on the page with this new player information

I thought maybe adding this data to my own backend would work, and maybe that is the answer, but even then I'm not sure how I can match that data up with the corresponding player ID's I'm already pulling from Sleeper's API. Currently, I am hitting all of the regular endpoints fine and having no issue displaying player ID numbers, I just want to swap those ID numbers for actual names. I fear I may have bitten off more that I can chew and this is a bit above my skill level. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If it helps, here is my JS file

```
//Capitalization function
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

// let test = 'this is a string'
// console.log(capitalizeFirstLetter(test))

// Accordion function
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
    to highlight the button that controls the panel */
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}


//Scoring Settings function
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                scoringData = result.scoring_settings
                $.map(scoringData, function(val, i) {
                    $('.accordion-list').append('<li>' + i +': ' + val)
                  });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                // console.log(err)
            }
    })
});


//Fetches team starters
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064/rosters',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            teamData = result.map(result => result.starters);
            teamData.forEach((starter, item) => {
                starter.forEach((entry) => { // loop the starter
                    $(`.starters-list${item}`).append('<li>'+entry+'</li>');
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
});


// Fetches total teams in league
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                playerData = result.total_rosters
                $('.rosters').append(playerData)
            },
            error: function(err) {
                // console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays owner names
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064/users',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                playerData = result.map(result => result.display_name);
                playerData.forEach((player, item) => {
                    $(`#player${item}`).append(player);
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                // console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays team names
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064/users',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                playerData = result.map(result => result.metadata.team_name);
                playerData.forEach((teamName, item) => {
                    $(`#team-name${item}`).append(teamName);
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                // console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays team avatar
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064/users',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                playerData = result.map(result => result.metadata.avatar);
                playerData.forEach((avatar, item) => {
                    $(`#avatar${item}`).attr("src", avatar)
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                // console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays information about draft
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/784456593403224065',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                draftData = result.type
                console.log(draftData)
                $('.draft-type').append(draftData)
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays draft status
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/784456593403224065',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                playerData = result.status
                console.log(playerData)
                $('.draft-status').append(playerData)
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays draft start time
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/784456593403224065',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                startData = result.start_time
                console.log(startData)
                $('.start-time').append(startData).JSON
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});


// Displays recently added players
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064/transactions/1',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                playerAdded = result.map(result => result.adds).slice(0, 15);
                let filteredPlayer = playerAdded.filter(player => player !== null)
                Object.values(filteredPlayer).forEach(value => {
                    console.log(value, filteredPlayer[value]);
                    $(`.added`).append('<li>'+JSON.stringify(value, filteredPlayer[value])+ '</li>')
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays recently dropped players
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064/transactions/1',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                playerDropped = result.map(result => result.drops).slice(0, 15);let filteredPlayer = playerDropped.filter(player => player !== null)
                Object.values(filteredPlayer).forEach(value => {
                    console.log(value, filteredPlayer[value]);
                    $(`.dropped`).append('<li>'+JSON.stringify(value, filteredPlayer[value])+ '</li>')
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays players trending up
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/players/nfl/trending/add?lookback_hours=240&limit=15',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                trendingUp = result.map(result => result.player_id);
                trendingUp.forEach((player) => {
                    $(`.trending-up`).append('<li>'+player+'</li>')
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

// Displays players trending down
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/players/nfl/trending/drop?lookback_hours=240&limit=15',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                trendingDown = result.map(result => result.player_id);
                trendingDown.forEach((player) => {
                    $(`.trending-down`).append('<li>'+player+'</li>')
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/comments',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                let commentData = result[0].comment_user +':' + result[0].comment_content
                console.log(commentData)
                $('.comment-section').append(commentData)
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});
```

And here is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="./js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Brick Dynasty Newsletter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="main-header">Brick Dynasty Newsletter</h1>
<!-- <button class="accordion">Scoring Settings &#xbb</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul class="accordion-list"></ul>
</div>
    <div class="league-info">
        <h1 class="rosters">Total Teams:</h1>
    </div> -->

    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="league-members-container">
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar0" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player0"></div>
            <div id="team-name0"></div>
                <ul class="starters-list0"></ul>
            </div>
            <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">    
            <img id="avatar1" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player1"></div>
            <div id="team-name1"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list1"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar2" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player2"></div>
            <div id="team-name2"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list2"></ul>
        </div>
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar3" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player3"></div>
        <div id="team-name3"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list3"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar4" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player4"></div>
            <div id="team-name4"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list4"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar5" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player5"></div>
            <div id="team-name5"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list5"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar6" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player6"></div>
            <div id="team-name6"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list6"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar7" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player7"></div>
            <div id="team-name7"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list7"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar8" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player8"></div>        
            <div id="team-name8"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list8"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar9" src="" alt="">     
            <div id="player9"></div>        
            <div id="team-name9"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list9"></ul>  
        </div>    
    </div>
<div class="player-movement-container">
    <h1 class="transaction-header">Recent Transactions</h1>
    <h1 class="trending-header">Trending</h1>
</div>    
<div class="player-movement">   
    <div class="transaction-container">
        <ul class="added">Added:</ul>
        <ul class="dropped">Dropped:</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="trending-down-container">
        <!-- <h1>Trending Down:</h1> -->
        <ul class="trending-down"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="trending-up-container">
        <!-- <h1>Trending Up:</h1> -->
        <ul class="trending-up"></ul>
    </div>
</div>     
</div>
<h1>What you need to know for the upcoming 2022 draft!</h1>
<div class="draft-container">
    <div class="draft-type"></div>
    <div class="draft-status"></div>
    <div class="start-time"></div>
</div>
<form method="POST" action="/comments">
    <input type="text" class="comment-box" name="comment_user" placeholder="test">
    <input type="textarea" class="comment-box" name="comment_content" placeholder="Leave a comment or talk some trash!">
    <button type="submit" class="comment-button">Comment</button>
</form>
<div class="comment-section">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try call the API to get the data on the server side and store in your database? Next time during the page rendering, you just fetch data from your own database instead of calling the API.

Comment: @SternChen I have not tried that, so I'm essentially calling the /players endpoint, then storing that on my own backend? Would I just make a POST request to save all of the data?